# NVIDIA GPU is driving my HDMI port but graphics are being done on Intel Integrated, resulting in almost unbearably low FPS

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hdmi

I'm using NVIDIA Driver Version 535.161.07 and my setup (Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4 LTS x64) is hooked up to two displays: both 1080p, one is 100hz the other is 144hz.

When I was using Xorg, the system used Nvidia GPU to draw everything. Okay, that was fine, but I found the interface was extremely laggy when I would try running Vulkan compute on the NVIDIA GPU; so I decided to use the Intel integrated graphics to draw everything and leave NVIDIA free for just compute by switching to Wayland. Almost 0 problems there.

The issue is that my HDMI port (connecting the 100hz display) seems to be internally wired to my NVIDIA GPU, and the Intel GPU has to communicate with it very fast. But it's not happening fast enough, according to intel_gpu_top... for example when I drag around a window I get roughly 40fps, but the Intel GPU is only being used about 60%! Confirmed that this is an issue with the NVIDIA chip or perhaps its driver. Everything is perceptibly choppier. The 144hz display, which is hooked up via eDP internally, is doing just fine however.

Is there a known fix or is this just another NVIDIA driver nuisance?